# frobenius map on primitive nth root of unity over Fp(w) with (n,p)=1

Tags: cyclotomic-fields

Suppose `w` is a primitive n-th root of unity, let `r = Ord_n(p)` (the smallest integer s.t. $p^r=1 \pmod n $), $f(w)=w^p$(the frobenius map), how to prove that $w,f(w),f^2(w),...f^{r-1}(w)$ are all different in `Fp(w)` so that the minimal monic polynomial of `w` over Fp factors into those r factors in `Fp(w)`?

Here if `w` is replaced with a primitive element of `Fp(w)` then it's easy to prove. But `w` is not a primitive element of `Fp(w)`, it's a primitive element of `Fp(w)/Fp`.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! You can improve the formatting of your post by [edit]ing it to use MathJax; see [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/228959) for a tutorial.

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip!